# can not sent curly brace and space in the URL using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, apache, xampp

I am trying to sent my data to the Apache (XAMPP)server using C#. In access log I found that curly brace and space are not coming. Later i found curly brace has become %7B and space become %. how to solve this problem.

Expected output=

> /vat/?data={site=123}"

Current output =

> "/vat/?data=%7Bsite=%20123%7D"

Here is my code and Apache access log picture.
[image]

```
 WebRequest reqst2 = WebRequest.Create("http://192.168.1.101/vat/?data={site=123}");
 WebResponse respons2 = reqst2.GetResponse();
```

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, would you mind marking it as the answer for others to see that it worked? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This comes down to an encoding issue. Try something like this:

```
string fixedUrl = System.Uri.UnescapeDataString(yourUrlHere);
```

Hope that helps!